# Is it possible to have SharePoint 2010 display a shared Exchange calendar?

Tags: exchange-server, calendar

Is it possible to have SharePoint 2010 display a shared Exchange calendar?

Software:

- Sharepoint Foundation 2010 - 64 bit
- Exchange 2003 - 32 bit

Comment: "If the user has access to a mailbox, the simple web page viewer web part can do the job, pointing to an url like https://<server name>/owa/tsmith@fourthcoffee.com" This will only work as you specify, if the user connected has permissions to see that mailbox. I am looking for a way to show availability of a ConferenceRoom on the sharepoint group calendar; if this isn't possible it's a huge letdown of the touted capability of SP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box, I do not believe so; and probably especially not in SharePoint Foundation. You can display SharePoint calendars in Outlook, but I do not believe that you can go direct to an Exchange calendar in SharePoint.

I did a quick search and found this web part that may or may not meet your needs. Obviously I've never used it so I can't comment on it, but it looks like there is a 2010 version and there is an evaluation version available.

http://www.amrein.com/apps/page.asp?Q=5778

Answer (score 8):

The accepted answer is incorrect. It is possible to display a shared Exchange calendar in SharePoint 2010. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-foundation-help/work-with-multiple-exchange-and-sharepoint-calendars-in-one-sharepoint-calendar-HA101777171.aspx

Comment: The overlay described at that link will allow you to overlay the user's outlook calendar onto the calendar.  However, for Exchange calendars, there is no way to specify what calendar to connect to (only the overlay's name) so Shared Calendars cannot be overlayed in that manner.  Unless you can provide additional information beyond the link you've provided, your answer appears to be incorrect.  However, if you can provide that additional information, there are a great many people on the internet who would be interested!

Comment: @antik I might be wrong, but wouldn't you just type in the Outlook Web Access URL and Exchange Web Service URL for whatever calendar you want to use?

Comment: I have experimented with that but I haven't found a way to do that successfully yet.  If you know how, please chime in and I'll happily stand corrected.  http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/17012/system-xml-xmlexception-when-using-sharepoint-exchange-calendar-overlay

Comment: Specific Exchange calendars are not anchorable via the URL; as far as I know, they don't work that way. You can only link to the gateway URL for Exchange and OWA, and SharePoint will use the credentials of the logged-in user to determine which calendar to display.

Answer (score 3):

You can use also 3-rd party solution from VirtoSoftware - [SharePoint Exchange Calendar Web Part](http://www.virtosoftware.com/sharepoint/calendar-web-part).
It supports 2013,2010 and 2007 SharePoint and all versions of Exchange Servers, including 2003 version.
Using this custom web part you'll be able to add to your existing SharePoint Calendar additional calendars as data sources from MS Exchange. You can add several Exchange calendars if needed. Also there is a permission manager there, so you can manage if SharePoint users will see some calendars or not.

Hope it will help you!

Answer (score 2):

this is described in this [technet article](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb232199.aspx).

If the user has access to a mailbox, the simple web page viewer web part can do the job, pointing to an url like `https://<server name>/owa/tsmith@fourthcoffee.com`

Comment: I've upvoted this answer because it's a good answer but it doesn't operate in my production network due to configuration reasons beyond my control.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question and we are running Exchange 2010 and SharePoint Server 2010 and it doesn't work out of the box. This is a huge let down and may cause us to rethink SharePoint entirely. You can connect to a SharePoint calendar to outlook but then you are sporadically prompted for your username and password. I would love to be proven wrong on this but anything else you read is misleading, it ONLY shows the Exchange calendar of whomever is logged into SharePoint.

Answer (score -1):

`https://<server name>/owa/tsmith@fourthcoffee.com/?cmd=contents&module=calendar` will give you the calendar, but it isn't accepted by Calendar Overlay in SharePoint.

Comment: I have seen this but I don't see how it can be used to target a specific shared mail box calendar for a team.

Comment: I have been testing this out with a Page Viewe Web Part.

Comment: https://exchange.mydomain/owa/?exsvurl=1&cmd=contents&module=Calendar gives me my cal in a page viewer web part. In an owa browser session, I can open a specific https://mydomain.com/owa/?ae=Folder&t=IPF.Communications but so far I have not been able to set this in my page viewer