# Existing Outlook Calendar to connect to a Sharepoint calendar

Tags: calendar, outlook

I have no problem creating a calendar and connecting that calendar to outlook but how do I go the other way?

I have an existing calendar in outlook with meetings and events that I would like to connect to a sharepoint calendar and have the roll up with others who also have existing outlook calendars, but I am not sure how to do this.

I think I could do this by doing a rollup. Going to > Calendars in view > new calendar > choosing exchange.. but I'm not sure if this is the right way (does this only get the default calendar?) or if there is a better way.

thanks

Comment: BTW I am using SP 2010

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want users to view their calendar, you can use the My Calendar web part (in Outlook Web App).

From my experience, adding an exchange calendar via Calendars in view only shows the status of the appointment, like busy, tentative, etc. You could connect a calendar to Outlook then drag your appointments from your calendar into the Outlook calendar as well, however this isn't ideal for an automated method.

Comment: I want to have several shared existing outlook calendars Like Events @ Location A Calendar and Events @ Location B Calendar.  I want the users to be able to update their calandars and the updates to appear on SP. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Are these shared calendars in Exchange/Outlook?

Comment: They are in Outlook.. Yes shared

Comment: Take a look at http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/6559/is-it-possible-to-have-sharepoint-2010-display-a-shared-exchange-calendar - 3rd party web part for displaying the calendar, and someone states a Calendar Overlay should work as well. HTH

Comment: These solutions will work for me http://sharepoint.indigoreality.com/2012/01/09/sharepoint-2010-connect-an-existing-outlook-calendar-to-sharepoint/                       http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T8w-cysDsyk

Comment: Oh good, I briefly watched the video, the other link isn't loading. You can keep your calendars side by side and drag events from one to the other. Much faster than what I saw in the video. HTH